# NsMutable Array search and conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have mutable array of class like :

```
@protocol CategoryModel @end

@interface CategoryModel : NSObject

@property (assign) int Id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* ShortString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* Description;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* AppId;

@end
```

I want to get an Nsdata of the AppId , how to do that

and I want to search this NsMutableArry by Id

Comment: And how did you try to do each thing? What API methods did you find the could help but which you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to get data from array by `Id`. You can use `NSPredicate` for this:

```
[myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id == %d", yourID]];
```

Comment: and what about create arry containing only the @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* AppId;

Comment: @AMH you can do it like `[myArray valueForKeyPath:@"self.AppId"];`